# When to use onResume and onPause method and how to use them in an android activity

Tags: android, mysql, android-activity

I need to design a Android app that connect with a mysql server. I need a login system for my app.

I am just confused when and how i should use `onResume` and `onPause` methods. When user types in username and password , if he/she switch to portrait to landscape or vise versa or if gets a phone call, my app would get crashed.

And while user type in login credentials , if user get a phone call , i need to persist the data he typed in the text fields and stay connected to the network instead of getting crashed.. How can i do this. This is my first app. thank you..

Comment: Refer this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: what research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Use saveinstancestate and restore instance state

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("photo_index", mCurrentPhotoIndex);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mCurrentPhotoIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("photo_index");
        showPhoto(mCurrentPhotoIndex);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```